# Running .dex file (written in smali) in Dalvik vm turns out to have a Verification Error

Tags: android, dalvik, smali

This 'HelloWorld' adds two numbers and prints out the answer

```
.class public LHelloWorld;
.super Ljava/lang/Object;
.method public static main([Ljava/lang/String;)V
  .registers 5
  .parameter
  .prologue
  const v0, 0x2
  const v1, 0x4
  add-int/2addr v0, v1
  new-instance v3, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
  invoke-direct {v3}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;-><init>()V
  const-string v3, "The result is : "
  sget-object v2, Ljava/lang/System;->out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
  invoke-virtual {v2, v3}, Ljava/lang/PrintStream;->print(Ljava/lang/String;)V
  invoke-virtual {v2, v0}, Ljava/lang/PrintStream;->println(Ljava/lang/Integer;)V
  return-void
.end method
```

And when I run the classes.dex on my Android device, adb shell give me an Error info

```
Unable to find static main(String[]) in 'HelloWorld'
java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class HelloWorld due to bad method void HelloWorld.main(java.lang.String[]) (declaration of 'HelloW
orld' appears in /storage/extSdCard/HelloWorld.zip)
```

I really don't understand why it turns out to be an error.

Please help,thanks.

Comment: You want to look for the art/dalvik verification logs that occur earlier, when it is running dexopt or dex2oat. These will point out the specific instruction, that is failing verification, and give some indication as to why it is failing.

Comment: @JesusFreke How can I get that log as you said? Would you please  explain that to me in detail, thank you.

Comment: The log should be in logcat.   "adb logcat"

Comment: @JesusFreke thanks！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where the problem is :
When print an int number (not an Integer object), the parameter type should be 'I' instead of 'Java/lang/Integer'.